# remove mm/dd/yyyy on placeholder input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, datepicker

We have on text filed input type date .So we need placedholder so we tried like this

```
<input placeholder="Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date">
```

Now it's showing placehoder "Date".Then i press it's showing `mm/dd/yyyy`.Then click it's showing Date box.But no need show `mm/dd/yyyy` .After click on textField directly open date box .Please guide to us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove default text/placeholder present in html5 input element of type=date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the previous discussions, you can not set the value to blank for JavaScript Date object. For more information refer to :[How to initialize java.util.date to empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168556/how-to-initialize-java-util-date-to-empty)

---

However,you can set the default values to a valid date. Refer to [How to set date value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_value.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Copying my answer from another post in case someone finds this and not that:  [CSS: Hide date mm/dd/yyyy placeholder on print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714221/css-hide-date-mm-dd-yyyy-placeholder-on-print/74790892#74790892)

It's a pure workaround, but I had the same issue and this was the simplest route:

```js
function RemoveClass(el, target_class) {
  el.classList.remove(target_class);
}
```

```css
.test {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" class="test" onclick="RemoveClass(this,'test');">
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply below css to your input box.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */

  color: white;

}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */

  color: white;

}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */

  color: white;

}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */

  color: white;

}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date">
```