# How to insert empty value in SQL date field in MSSQL?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pojo, ibatis

I am setting java object, having one property/field with an empty string.
I am passing that java object to ibatis to insert in database.
In database, table having a column with 'date' type. I am trying to insert empty string into that column but it is inserting some random values like '1900-01-01'.
I have tried with setting null and more but nothing is possible. Help me out with the solution

Comment: It depends how your column is defined. If you need null values, make the column nullable, else you are forced to provide a date.

Comment: If the question is unclear just dont react anything

Comment: I have tried making column nullable and also tried with default constraint but not worked

Answer (score 0):

if there is no value inserted, the default value should be null,empty
In the table definition, make this datetime column allows null, be not defining NOT NULL:

Or, you can make use of the DEFAULT constaints:

syntax-DateColumn Date DEFAULT NULL

Comment: Hi, I have done both the cases but i am not getting expected

Answer (score 0):

This issue is about Java, not SQL Server. You can't assign null to the Date variable - check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168556/how-to-initialize-java-util-date-to-empty). I suggest you can just don't pass this column and create DEFAULT constraint for it in the database.